# How can I use Zend_Auth with Zend_Json_Server?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-session

[Zend's JSON-RPC server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.server.html) doesn't seem to like sessions, and I can't seem to attach a session even by passing `Zend_Session::getId()` in to my RPC method and revive it with `Zend_Session::setId($session_id)` as I might expect.

**To illustrate what does NOT work:**

```
<?php

$server = new Zend_Json_Server();
$server->setClass('MyRPC');
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    myrpc = jQuery.Zend.jsonrpc({
        url : <?=json_encode($this->baseUrl('/ajax'))?>
        , smd : <?=$server->getServiceMap()?>
        , async : true
    });
    myrpc.getIdentity(<?=json_encode(Zend_Session::getId())?>, {
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data.user_id);
        }
    });
});
// see: http://www.tanabi.com/projects/jsonrpc

</script>
```

and in my RPC class:

```
<?php

class MyRPC {

    /**
     * @param string
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentity($session_id) {
        \Zend_Session::setId($session_id);
        \Zend_Session::start();
        // returns NULL
        return \Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is [unimplemented](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Json/Server/Server.php#L215).